# Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, virtualenv

I have just installed Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 using the `./configure`, `make`, `make install` process.  I am trying to install Flask, and am having issues using `pip` in `virtualenv` created with 3.4. Using `pip` installs to Python 2.7, `pip3` installs to 3.5. Trying any other method produces errors.

How do I invoke pip for Python 3.4.3?

Answer (score 4):

Revised from [Creating a virtual environment with python3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://web.archive.org/web/20160923194125/http://devmartin.com/blog/2016/04/creating-a-virtual-environment-with-python3.4-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial-xerus/):

> 1. Install dependencies.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall  
>    sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev openssl
>    ```
> 2. Get python3.4 source code.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir -p $HOME/opt  
>    cd $HOME/opt  
>    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz  
>    tar xzvf Python-3.4.3.tgz  
>    cd Python-3.4.3
>    ```
> 3. Configure and install.
>
>    ```
>    ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib"  
>    sudo make altinstall
>    ```
>
>    `--enable-shared` is necessary for some libraries. The `--prefix` is needed for reasons (more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library/26657830#26657830)).
>      `make altinstall` keeps your python3.5 installation as the default one.
> 4. Create a python3.4 virtualenv.
>
>    Now we can create a new virtual environment and activate it:
>
>    ```
>    python3.4 -m venv Python3.4VirtualEnv  
>    . Python3.4VirtualEnv/bin/activate
>    ```

pip3 is installed by default when the Python 3.4 virtual environment is created. List installed packages:

```
pip3 list
```

Returns

```
Flask (0.11.1)
```

Type `flask --help` to show Flask help. This output shows that Flask has been successfully installed in a Python virtual environment for Python 3.4.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this didn't work for me even after a complete 16.04 re-install.  I reverted back to 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific version, you could do:

```
pip install 'python==3.4.3' --force-reinstall
```

or

```
pip install 'python3==3.4.3' --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

`python3.4 -m pip install <packageYouWant>`

The same is true if you wanted to specify 3.5 packages:

`python3.5 -m pip install <packageYouWant>`

Link is here: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/installing/)