# pip won't run without sudo

Tags: package-management, python, sudo, pip

I have changed my username recently on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have also changed the home folder.
Now that I try to install any package using pip, I get this error.

```
bash: /home/hasnain/Downloads/Programs/123456/bin/pip: /home/hassaan/Downloads/Programs/123456/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Where `hasnain` is my new username while the old username was `hassaan`. pip runs fine with `sudo`, but the packages installed using `sudo pip` can only be run using `sudo`.
How do I use pip without `sudo`?

Comment: [Installing software with python pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557280/installing-software-with-python-pip)

Comment: @karel thanks. But this isn't a permanent fix, right?
I want to be able to use it on system.

Comment: In a way a it kind of is a permanent fix because installing with pip locally without sudo doesn't always work because pip or some other package isn't up to date to the latest version and installing with pip inside a Python virtual environment reduces the probability of failed Python package installations while adding an additional layer of security. If you make a mistake you can always fix it no matter what by deleting the Python virtual environment and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `apt` or `apt-get` to install `pip`. You will probably need to uninstall your locally installed version of `pip` if you do this.

You can run the following commands to install `pip`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

To install `python3-pip`, use the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Instead of using a virtual environment, you can install stuff with the `--user` flag.

Here is an example of how to install `youtube-dl` using this method:

```
pip install --user youtube-dl
```

Here is an example of how to update `youtube-dl` using the same method:

```
pip install --user --upgrade youtube-dl
```